# "Не-" с причастием

Tags: грамматика

Подскажите, верно ли написаны слова с *не-*: «отмена фактически не действующих, но не отмененных в установленном порядке нормативных актов»?

Answer (score 1):

"Не" с причастием пишется раздельно, если есть зависимые слова. Но если зависимое слово подчеркивает утверждение, то причастие с НЕ пишется слитно. Поэтому во втором случае точно раздельно, а для первого хорошо бы знать контекст. Слово "фактически" - в прямом значении (фактически, а не теоретически) - тогда раздельно, а если в значении "совсем" (степень проявления признака), тогда слитно.